# Fundamental django project deployment information

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, django-deployment

I am a newbie in Django deployment and have been given the task of the project deployment on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS prod server.

I have already deployed the project using NginX and uWSGI by copying all the project files in a directory with appropriate permissions and also assigned respective permissions to www-data user.

But, my question is whether all the files need to be directly copied into the said directory (since python files are interpreted files) or is there any other format, such as a war file for jsp projects, that can be directly deployed instead of copying the directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general Django projects are deployed

- either as a directory of source files and the accompanying virtualenv, or
- as a self-contained container of some sort (e.g. Docker).

In the former case, I really wouldn't manually copy anything, but have the directory be a checkout from your version control system (e.g. Git).

Comment: Thank you so much, it was really helpful.